# How can I get a specific field within my table where the ID is the max id?

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how to create an sql procedure to get a JobID as LastJobID where the ID is the max.

My procedure looks like this as of right now : `` `SELECT MAX( ID ) as LastJobID FROM jobs;` ``

But I need something like this: `` `SELECT JobID as LastJobID FROM jobs where MAX( ID );` ``

The latter gives me an error.

My table consists of a unique auto incremented ID, JobID and other attributes as well.  I just need to get the JobID from the Max( ID ) because the JobID's are Alpha numeric so getting the MAX( JobID ) won't get me correct results.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, but if anyone has an idea of a procedure that would let me do this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT JobID as LastJobID FROM 
  jobs 
  where id =
  ( select MAX( ID ) from jobs)
```